# How to match 3D perspective of real photo and object in CSS3 3D transforms

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

**The situation:**

In my particular case I have 3D photoframe image and a 2D photo. And I want the 2D photo to match the 3D frame using CSS3 transform functions (Rotate, Scale, Skew).

**The problem:**

I wasn't able to precisely match the two using manual method aka typing rotation value and watching what it does.

**Ideal solution #1**

Online visual **tool** exists that lets you drag corners of the photo (like photoshop does) and It gives you the correct CSS3 transform values.

**Ideal solution #2**

Non-visual tool exist - same as before but you manually enter 4 point coordinates (image corners) and it gives you the correct CSS3 transform values.

**Real solution of this question**

If there aren't such tools (my search found none) I would like somebody to try **explain** the math behind it so I could calculate it myself - If it is even **possible**?

I prepared JSFiddle demo for you fiddle around:
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/marakoss/67ov5h8k/)

```css
/* Main issue here */

.transform {
  transform: rotateX(34deg) rotateZ(13deg) rotateY(-10deg) scaleY(1) scaleX(1) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) translateY(0px) translateX(20px);
  transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
}
/* Supporting styles */

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.frame,
.photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.photo {
  top: 50px;
  left: 95px;
  right: 65px;
  bottom: 270px;
}
.frame img,
.photo img {
  width: 100%
}
.frame {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="frame">
    <img src="http://cdn.idesigned.cz/img/cc08acc7b9b08ab53bf935d720210f13.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="photo">
    <div class="transform">
      <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7976/pexels-photo.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you can use 3-d transforms (such as `rotateZ`), then you can also provide `matrix3d` which you can compute from desired point correspondences.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szym/03s5mwjv/

I'm using [numeric.js](http://www.numericjs.com/) to solve a set of 4 linear equations to find the perspective transform matrix that transforms `src` onto `dst`. This is essentially the same math as in [`getPerspectiveTransform` in OpenCV](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/bad09e5f584d54ca1471cd9f01a040e1dd97fdfe/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L6242).

The computed 2-d perspective transform is a 3x3 matrix using [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The CSS `matrix3d` is a 4x4 matrix using homogeneous coordinates, so we need to add an identity row/column for the `z` axis. Furthermore, `matrix3d` is specified in column-major order.

Once you get the `matrix3d` you can just paste it into your stylesheet. But keep in mind that the matrix is computed assuming `(0, 0)` as origin, so you also need to set `transformOrigin: 0 0`.

```js
// Computes the matrix3d that maps src points to dst.
function computeTransform(src, dst) {
  // src and dst should have length 4 each
  var count = 4;
  var a = []; // (2*count) x 8 matrix
  var b = []; // (2*count) vector

  for (var i = 0; i < 2 * count; ++i) {
    a.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    b.push(0);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var j = i + count;
    a[i][0] = a[j][3] = src[i][0];
    a[i][1] = a[j][4] = src[i][1];
    a[i][2] = a[j][5] = 1;
    a[i][3] = a[i][4] = a[i][5] =
      a[j][0] = a[j][1] = a[j][2] = 0;
    a[i][6] = -src[i][0] * dst[i][0];
    a[i][7] = -src[i][1] * dst[i][0];
    a[j][6] = -src[i][0] * dst[i][1];
    a[j][7] = -src[i][1] * dst[i][1];
    b[i] = dst[i][0];
    b[j] = dst[i][1];
  }

  var x = numeric.solve(a, b);
  // matrix3d is homogeneous coords in column major!
  // the z coordinate is unused
  var m = [
    x[0], x[3],   0, x[6],
    x[1], x[4],   0, x[7],
       0,    0,   1,    0,
    x[2], x[5],   0,    1
  ];
  var transform = "matrix3d(";
  for (var i = 0; i < m.length - 1; ++i) {
    transform += m[i] + ", ";
  }
  transform += m[15] + ")";
  return transform;
}

// Collect the four corners by user clicking in the corners
var dst = [];
document.getElementById('frame').addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  // Make sure the coordinates are within the target element.
  var box = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var point = [evt.clientX - box.left, evt.clientY - box.top];
  dst.push(point);

  if (dst.length == 4) {
    // Once we have all corners, compute the transform.
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    var w = img.width,
        h = img.height;
    var transform = computeTransform(
      [
        [0, 0],
        [w, 0],
        [w, h],
        [0, h]
      ],
      dst
    );
    document.getElementById('photo').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('transform').style.transformOrigin = '0 0';
    document.getElementById('transform').style.transform = transform;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = transform;
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
  
#frame,
#photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
  
#photo {
  visibility: hidden;
}
  
#frame img,
#photo img {
  width: 100%
}
  
#photo {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeric/1.2.6/numeric.min.js"></script>
  <p id="result">Click the desired top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left corners
  <div class="container">
    <div id="frame">
      <img src="http://cdn.idesigned.cz/img/cc08acc7b9b08ab53bf935d720210f13.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="photo">
      <div id="transform">
        <img id="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Wow man! You surpassed my expectations. Thank you. The bounty is yours.

Comment: On the second look it completely doesn't solve my issue due to possibility of   breaking aspect ratio of the photo, but I think it can by solved with another tier of encapsulation. - You can edit your answer to address this issue.

Comment: Technically, perspective transform does not preserve aspect ratio, but there's a way to check if it does. You'd also have to decide how to clip the image if aspect ratio cannot be matched.

Comment: Outstanding answer.  (Took me a painfully long time to find!)

Comment: Great answer! I know it's a little old but... it's still work perfect and will help me in my project!

Answer (score 6):

I've written [an answer on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/339033/35416) about how to compute the transformation matrix to map the corners of one image to four given coordinates using a projective transformation. It has details of what's actually going on in that computation. It also has some CSS and I adapted [the original demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dFrHS/1/) to your example scenario:

```js
function adj(m) { // Compute the adjugate of m
  return [
    m[4]*m[8]-m[5]*m[7], m[2]*m[7]-m[1]*m[8], m[1]*m[5]-m[2]*m[4],
    m[5]*m[6]-m[3]*m[8], m[0]*m[8]-m[2]*m[6], m[2]*m[3]-m[0]*m[5],
    m[3]*m[7]-m[4]*m[6], m[1]*m[6]-m[0]*m[7], m[0]*m[4]-m[1]*m[3]
  ];
}
function multmm(a, b) { // multiply two matrices
  var c = Array(9);
  for (var i = 0; i != 3; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j != 3; ++j) {
      var cij = 0;
      for (var k = 0; k != 3; ++k) {
        cij += a[3*i + k]*b[3*k + j];
      }
      c[3*i + j] = cij;
    }
  }
  return c;
}
function multmv(m, v) { // multiply matrix and vector
  return [
    m[0]*v[0] + m[1]*v[1] + m[2]*v[2],
    m[3]*v[0] + m[4]*v[1] + m[5]*v[2],
    m[6]*v[0] + m[7]*v[1] + m[8]*v[2]
  ];
}
function basisToPoints(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) { // map basis to these points
  var m = [
    x1, x2, x3,
    y1, y2, y3,
     1,  1,  1
  ];
  var v = multmv(adj(m), [x4, y4, 1]);
  return multmm(m, [
    v[0], 0, 0,
    0, v[1], 0,
    0, 0, v[2]
  ]);
}
function general2DProjection(
  x1s, y1s, x1d, y1d,
  x2s, y2s, x2d, y2d,
  x3s, y3s, x3d, y3d,
  x4s, y4s, x4d, y4d
) {
  console.log(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ", "));
  var s = basisToPoints(x1s, y1s, x2s, y2s, x3s, y3s, x4s, y4s);
  var d = basisToPoints(x1d, y1d, x2d, y2d, x3d, y3d, x4d, y4d);
  return multmm(d, adj(s));
}
function transform2d(elt, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {
  var w = elt.offsetWidth, h = elt.offsetHeight;
  var t = general2DProjection
    (0, 0, x1, y1, w, 0, x2, y2, 0, h, x3, y3, w, h, x4, y4);
  for(i = 0; i != 9; ++i) t[i] = t[i]/t[8];
  t = [t[0], t[3], 0, t[6],
       t[1], t[4], 0, t[7],
       0   , 0   , 1, 0   ,
       t[2], t[5], 0, t[8]];
  t = "matrix3d(" + t.join(", ") + ")";
  elt.style["-webkit-transform"] = t;
  elt.style["-moz-transform"] = t;
  elt.style["-o-transform"] = t;
  elt.style.transform = t;
}

corners = [100, 50, 300, 50, 100, 150, 300, 150];
function update() {
  var box = document.getElementById("photo");
  transform2d(box, corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3],
                   corners[4], corners[5], corners[6], corners[7]);
  for (var i = 0; i != 8; i += 2) {
    var elt = document.getElementById("marker" + i);
    elt.style.left = corners[i] + "px";
    elt.style.top = corners[i + 1] + "px";
  }
  document.getElementById("matrix").textContent = box.style.transform;
}
function move(evnt) {
  if (currentcorner < 0) return;
  corners[currentcorner] = evnt.pageX;
  corners[currentcorner + 1] = evnt.pageY;
  console.log(corners);
  update();
}
currentcorner = -1;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.documentElement.style.margin="0px";
  document.documentElement.style.padding="0px";
  document.body.style.margin="0px";
  document.body.style.padding="0px";
  update();
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evnt) {
  var x = evnt.pageX, y = evnt.pageY, dx, dy;
  var best = 400; // 20px grab radius
  currentcorner = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i != 8; i += 2) {
    dx = x - corners[i];
    dy = y - corners[i + 1];
    if (best > dx*dx + dy*dy) {
      best = dx*dx + dy*dy;
      currentcorner = i;
    }
  }
  move(evnt);
  evnt.preventDefault();
}, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evnt) {
  currentcorner = -1;
}, true)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', move, true);
```

```css
/* Supporting styles */

#photo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 0% 0% 0;
}
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: -0.5ex;
  padding: 0ex;
  width: 1ex;
  height: 1ex;
  border-radius: 0.5ex;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<img id="photo" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/7976/pexels-photo.jpg" />
<img class="frame" src="http://cdn.idesigned.cz/img/cc08acc7b9b08ab53bf935d720210f13.png" />
<div class="dot" id="marker0"></div>
<div class="dot" id="marker2"></div>
<div class="dot" id="marker4"></div>
<div class="dot" id="marker6"></div>
<div id="matrix"></div>
```

The formulation is such that you can make it working with merely three arithmetic operations: `+`, `-` and `*`. You don't even need `/` (if you use adjunct instead of inverse matrices), much less case distinctions, square roots, or any other such things.

If you prefer Stack Overflow (and to get a cross reference established), see [Redraw image from 3d perspective to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244616/1468366).

Comment: Thank you. Your visual tool is better than the accepted answer. If you polish your answer so it matches my question I would reconsider the accepted answer.

Comment: In what way would you like to see this polished to better match your question? There is the tool to simply drag corners (in the form of my demo), adapting that to work on written input should be easy, and the math explanations are there in the other posts, so I don't think I should copy all of that again. Do you want to see it applied to your example?

Comment: I would like the answer to be definitive for anybody who comes across my question. The previous accepted answer helped me solve my issue. Yours has better demo. If you combine those I would be happy..

Comment: @Marakoss: I don't wish to combine my answer with the accepted answer, because I I wouldn't do things the way szym does them. Solving a 4×4 system of equations without the help of a third-party library is pretty tedious, and completely avoidable here. Having a 1 in the bottom right corner means you run into trouble if the top left corner ends up at infinity. Can't happen if you directly drag the corners, but I'm nonetheless surprised opencv does things this way, as it makes the code less generic than it could be. I've adapted my demo, although I think my MSE post is more valuable than that.

Comment: This peace of fantastic! code just save my life, but i was wondering..is it possible to add span also? i mean, not only streck/skew the image but also move it around.

Comment: @Japa: I have problems understanding your question. You can move the image around in the target coordinate system by moving all four corners in parallel. You can move the image within the source coordinate system by moving the corresponding preimage coordinates. The projective transformation used here is more than a combination of affine transformation like skew. I don't know what you mean by “streck” or “span” here.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @szym code I've created a demo for my needs that can be improved. The code uses draggable points so it's easier to find the points and calculate the matrix. Also the matrix is printed on the left.

```css
// Computes the matrix3d that maps src points to dst.
function compute_transform(src, dst) {
  // src and dst should have length 4 each
  var count = 4;
  var a = []; // (2*count) x 8 matrix
  var b = []; // (2*count) vector

  for (var i = 0; i < 2 * count; ++i) {
    a.push([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    b.push(0);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    var j = i + count;
    a[i][0] = a[j][3] = src[i][0];
    a[i][1] = a[j][4] = src[i][1];
    a[i][2] = a[j][5] = 1;
    a[i][3] = a[i][4] = a[i][5] =
      a[j][0] = a[j][1] = a[j][2] = 0;
    a[i][6] = -src[i][0] * dst[i][0];
    a[i][7] = -src[i][1] * dst[i][0];
    a[j][6] = -src[i][0] * dst[i][1];
    a[j][7] = -src[i][1] * dst[i][1];
    b[i] = dst[i][0];
    b[j] = dst[i][1];
  }

  var x = numeric.solve(a, b);
  // matrix3d is homogenous coords in column major!
  // the z coordinate is unused
  var m = [
    x[0], x[3], 0, x[6],
    x[1], x[4], 0, x[7],
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    x[2], x[5], 0, 1
  ];
  return "matrix3d(" + m.join(',') + ')';
}

// Collect the four corners by user clicking in the corners:

var points = [];
// map flatten the array
$('.point').each(function() {
    var {left, top} = $(this).position();
    points.push([left, top]);
});

transform_terminal();

$('.point').each(function(i) {
    var drag = false;
    var [container] = $('.laptop');
    var $point = $(this).mousedown(function() {
        drag = true;
    });
    $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
        drag = false;
    }).on('mousemove', function(event) {
        if (drag) {
            var box = container.getBoundingClientRect();
            var x = event.clientX - box.left;
            var y = event.clientY - box.top;
            points[i] = [x, y];
            $point.css({
                left: x,
                top: y
            });
            transform_terminal();
        }
    });
});

function transform_terminal() {
    var w = gemetry.width + 20,
        h = gemetry.height + 20;
    var transform = compute_transform(
        [
            [0, 0],
            [w, 0],
            [w, h],
            [0, h]
        ],
        points
    );
    $('.output pre').html(`
.terminal {
    transform: ${transform};
}
    `.trim())
    term.css({
        '--transform': transform
    });
}
```

[See demo in Action](https://codepen.io/jcubic/full/PojPbZz) I use it to match jQuery Terminal into an image of a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that it is difficult to find a tool or formula for this.
If you know the angles and measures of the book it is easy to calculate I think.
[W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-function-lists) here you can find more detailed information about the transformations
but as I said, without the details of your image (the book) I have no idea how you could calculate the exact coordinates.

The only thing that could help you is the *css perspective*.
I have made a [**Plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cqTNI2F8c5AB7X4LVWmj?p=preview) that you can see how it looks like with it.

The only things that I changed are:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
}
```

and

```
.transform{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(19deg) rotateZ(6deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleY(0.85) scaleX(0.85) skewY(0deg) skewX(-8deg) translateY(-10px) translateX(33px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    transform: rotateX(19deg) rotateZ(6deg) rotateY(0deg) scaleY(0.85) scaleX(0.85) skewY(0deg) skewX(-8deg) translateY(-10px) translateX(33px);
    transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
 }
```

The photo doesn't fit exactly in the frame because it's a square but
I hope that helps you a bit further.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your effort. Unfortunately I can't accept your answer as its not universal answer and others in the same situation can't figure out how to do this on their own.