# World to camera coordinates

Tags: math, 3d

What is the transformation matrix V that converts points from world coordinates to camera coordinates such that the camera y-axis is the world's y-axis. The camera looks towards the world's x-axis and the camera is located at(5,0,5)?

Comment: This is a fairly complex issue.  There is a tutorial at https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrices-what-you-need-to-know-first which may be useful.

Comment: see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) You are missing some important details like properties of screen and world coordinate systems, projection type ... and also matrix convention and multiplication order

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Finding the Transform matrix from 4 projected points (with Javascript)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/296794/35416) or [Redraw image from 3d perspective to 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14244032/1468366) or [How to match 3D perspective of real photo and object in CSS3 3D transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36050537/1468366) for how to define a map between world plane and camera plane given 4 points and their images. Your preservation of the *y* axis could translate into preservation of the point at infinity in the *y* direction, at least if you mean that *all* parallel lines in the *y* direction are preserved, not just the single axis. If you move the camera location to the 3d origin, then you can treat the 3d vectors of your world coordinates as homogeneous coordinates in a 2d view of that world by the camera.